Hermiticity of a matrix that depends on a symbol
Suppose I have a real number $x$, and I want to check the hermicity of the matrix $A=x\sigma_x$, here $\sigma_x$ is the Pauli matrix $\{\{0,1\},\{1,0\}\}$, I run the code
Assuming[Element[x, Reals], HermitianMatrixQ[x PauliMatrix[1]]]

But I got a "False" output. What should I do if I want to get a "True" output?
When the expression of $A$ becomes more complicated, it seems impossible to use Mathematica to check the hermicity of the matrix $A$.

Welcome to Mathematica SE. From the HermitianMatrixQ documentation, try HermitianMatrixQ[m, SameTest -> (Simplify[#1 - #2, Element[x, Reals]] == 0 &)], where m = x PauliMatrix[1]. Does this solve the problem when the expression is more complicated?

Thanks so much for the warm welcome and for your really helpful suggestion! I tried it on my more complex expression, and it solved the issue perfectly. I really appreciate your time and help! Thanks again!
